# Change a WHERE clause if a parameter is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

How should I amend the following, which is part of a stored procedure, so that `pd.PackageID  = @PackageId OR` becomes `pd.PackageID  = @PackageId AND` only if @PackageId is not null?

```
        pd.PackageID  = @PackageId OR
        FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber, @SearchText)  OR
        FREETEXT(o.DisplayLocation, @SearchText)  OR
        FREETEXT(o.SearchTitle, @SearchText)  OR
        FREETEXT(o.WebKeyword, @SearchText)  OR
```

If PackageID and SearchText both have values then it should be

```
    pd.PackageID  = @PackageId AND
    FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber, @SearchText)  OR
    FREETEXT(o.DisplayLocation, @SearchText)  OR
    FREETEXT(o.SearchTitle, @SearchText)  OR
    FREETEXT(o.WebKeyword, @SearchText)  OR
```

If only PackageID has a value then I can get away with only evaluating

```
pd.PackageID  = @PackageId
WHERE
```

Comment: Don't write such queries in the first place. It results in bad execution plans. [This article explains the problem](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/revisiting-catch-all-queries). The easiest way would be to generate dynamic queries using eg EF, including only valid parameters. Even if you use string concatenation you'll be safe as long as you don't include user input in the query.

Comment: Appreciate that if `@PackageId` be null, then the first part of the `AND` would always be false.  What should happen if `@PackageId` is null?

Comment: If you have to check in the stored procedure, notice that most of the WHERE clause needs the *same* check. It would be simpler *and* avoid bad execution plans if you used an `IF (@SearchText IS NULL)` statement to either execute `SELECT ... WHERE pd.PackageID  = @PackageId` alone or the full query

Comment: [FREETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) accepts a column list which means you can replace all `FREETEXT` checks with a single one: `FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber,o.DisplayLocation,....,@SearchText)`

Comment: Use `IF` and replicate exactly what the question says in the stored procedure `IF @PackageI IS IS NOT NULL AND @SearchText IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT WHERE pd.PackageID  = @PackageId AND FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber, o.DisplayLocation,...,@SearchText) ELSE IF @SearchText is NULL THEN SELECT ... WHERE pd.PackageID=@PackageID ELSE .....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can use a single [FREETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) call instead of multiple ones. FREETEXT accepts a single column, a column list or *. You can replace the multiple calls with just:

```
FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber, o.DisplayLocation, o.SearchTitle, o.WebKeyword, @SearchText)
```

Second, *don't* use such [catch-all queries](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/revisiting-catch-all-queries) because they usually result in bad execution plans. If the first call has a `@PackageID` but no @SearchText, the query engine will probably create an execution plan that uses an Index Seek on `pd.PackageID` and only calculates the FTS clause without using the FTS index. This will result in bad performance for queries that only use FTS.

The best option (fastest, easiest to maintain, easier to write) is to use an IF clause to execute different queries:

```
IF @PackageI IS IS NOT NULL AND @SearchText IS NOT NULL THEN 
    SELECT 
    ...
    WHERE pd.PackageID  = @PackageId 
        AND 
        FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber, o.DisplayLocation, o.SearchTitle, o.WebKeyword, @SearchText)
ELSE IF @SearchText is NULL THEN 
    SELECT
    ... 
    WHERE pd.PackageID=@PackageID 
ELSE 
    SELECT
    ...
    WHERE 
        FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber, o.DisplayLocation, o.SearchTitle, o.WebKeyword, @SearchText)
```

If you absolutely have to put everything in the same query (BIG WHY????), you'll have to use `RECOMPILE` in the stored procedure or query, to force recompilation of the query every time. This will lead to reduced performance, especially if the stored procedure is called frequently:

```
SELECT 
...
WHERE 
    (@PackageID IS NULL OR pd.PackageID  = @PackageId) 
    AND 
    (@SearchText IS NULL OR FREETEXT(o.ObjectNumber, o.DisplayLocation, o.SearchTitle, o.WebKeyword, @SearchText))
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```